# Lollipop AOSP app locations

Tags: android, android-source

I'm working on developing a better understanding of Android internals by creating my own custom ROM for my Nexus 5. I figured, to start, I should try making a ROM which removes many of the apps I don't use that are in the Nexus 5 Lollipop factory image.

A few of the apps I want to get rid of:
Fit
Email (this app just points to gmail)
Play books (I'm old school, I still like paper books)
Play Games
Play Newstand

There are various .mk files which will use PRODUCT_PACKAGES to select which apps to build an include. I know there is build/target/product/core.mk, but I don't see any of the above apps listed there. I tried grepping the entire AOSP for "fitness" and nothing turned up.

- What are all the typical places PRODUCT_PACKAGES are listed?
- Where would the source for these apps be located? I don't see them in the /packages/apps directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in AOSP, the open source for Android, for packages that are not open source.  The two apps you named are proprietary Google apps and not part of AOSP.

If you just build AOSP, the image you get will not include those two apps.

You are correct, though, that most system apps are in the packages directory.

Comment: Just flashed it, you're right. I feel stupid. >=\ I'll mark this as the answer. I was under the impression that what is downloaded and compiled is the same as the factory images that are posted on the Google website.

Comment: Right.  Not at all.  Both device manufacturers and carriers customize the source from which they build the Android that gets installed on a phone.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I might go about adding some apps I want in there like Google Play? I know how to include apps which I have the source for, but I'm not sure how to include apps with only the .apk. I figure I would need to do that for Google play.

Comment: You probably can't get the source for Google Play.  You can find it around, as a zip, and install it from recovery.  Adding your own app just requires getting it noticed by the build system.  Look at the Android.mk files in packages that are similar to yours.  If you are familiar with NDK, you'll see what's going on pretty quickly.  Karim Yaghmour's book is a great resource.

Comment: I found a Google Play APK. I was able to get it to be installed in my system image, but when I try to open it, it crashes. Sounds like if I want to include a 3rd party app, I'm supposed to handle this some other way?

Comment: Play depends on several other things.  I don't really know the space well, but I'm sure that it depends, at least, on a corresponding version of Google Play Services.  Have a look at CyanogenMod.  I know that they make it possible, in some shadowy way, to get the Google suite running on their fork of Android.